# Populating a select from a static Web Method in code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have to dynamically populate a select from code behind file. I was able to do that from Page_load, but unable to do it from a static web method. It says "
an object reference is required to access the non static field..."

```
 <div style="margin-left: 24%; display: inline-block" runat="server">
  <label style="margin-top: 3%">Select Voice Product</label>
  <button type="button" style="margin-top: 3%;" class="qual toDisable" id="btnAddVoicetToSelected" onclick="btnAddVoice()">Add Voice</button>
 <select id="selectedVoiceProducts" runat="server" name="VoiceProducts" style="margin-top: 3%;">
<option label="Select Voice Product" value="-1">Select</option>
 </select>
      </div>
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]

pulic static void Populate(){
    selectedVoiceProducts.Items.Add(new ListItem("SomeItem","SomeValue");//error here
}
```

Comment: You can't do that from a static method. You need to return a JSON from your method and bind it on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. 
You are accessing a server control (instance) from a static method which is not possible.

if you want to pass the options out - return an ArrayList and let the caller consume this information

see detailed solution [here](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/)